# Most efficient way in MySQL to get all associated values from a relation table while filtering after the same values

Tags: mysql, sql

Simplified I have two tables in MySQL: One holding a sort of person entity and one relation table which associates multiple rights two the person entity. The tables look like:

person

```
person_id | person_name
1         | Michael
2         | Kevin
```

person2right

```
person_id | right_id
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 4
2         | 1
2         | 2
```

What I want to achieve now is getting all persons including all associated rights, which have at least the defined rights - right_id 1 and 4 in this example.

What I have so far is a query with subselect, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to achieve my goal without the subselect, because of MySQL not being able to use an index when joining a subselect. Here is my query:

```
SELECT person_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`person2right`.`right_id`) as `all_rights` 
FROM `person` 
LEFT JOIN `person2right` ON `person`.`person_id` = `person2right`.`person_id` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `person_id` FROM `person2right` WHERE `right_id` IN (1, 4) 
    GROUP BY `person_id` HAVING COUNT(`person2right`.`right_id`) >= 2
) as `p2r` ON `person`.`person_id` = `p2r`.`person_id` 
WHERE `p2r`.`person_id` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `person_id`
```

Maybe someone has an idea to do it without the subquery. Appriciate your help.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Do you need the `right_id` values in a single 'cell'? (the `group_concat()` tells me the answer is 'yes')

Comment: Yes I do. The final result must be a list of persons with all their associated right_ids in a single column.

Comment: I think your approach is quite good... Of course, the question now is: is your query too slow?

Comment: With several thousand person records, it is not that slow. But i was wondering what will be when there are millions of records. I know that no index can be used when joining the subselect. So there might be a potential bottleneck.

Comment: Why do you say that no index can be used when joining the subquery? I couldn't find good references but to the opposite: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Comment: You could also insert millions test records in your table and check if performance or cost will really be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only select persons (and all their associated rights) who have both rights 1 and 4. Note that it's different from your query in that your query selects all persons (regardless of their rights) and only selects their associated rights if they have rights 1 and 4.

```
SELECT person_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`person2right`.`right_id`) as `all_rights` 
FROM `person` 
JOIN `person2right` ON `person`.`person_id` = `person2right`.`person_id` 
GROUP BY `person`.`person_id`
HAVING SUM(`right_id` = 4) > 0 AND SUM(`right_id` = 1) > 0
```

**Edit:** if the rows in `person2right` are unique, then you can change your `having` clause to

```
HAVING SUM(`right_id` IN (1,4)) = 2
```

Comment: Why do you think, that my query selects all persons regardless of their rights? I only select persons that's id is result of the subquery which returns only person ids that have the two rights. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Okay, I tested your solution. It seems to be very, very effected. Just a single join is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @S-Buzz because you're using left joins (instead of a inner joins) your query will select all rows from the `person` table even when the join conditions are not fulfilled

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if additional joins can do the trick:

```
select person_name, group_concat(distinct p2r.right_id) as all_rights
from person as p
     inner join person2right as p2r using (person_id) -- You don't need LEFT JOIN, because you'll only return persons with rights
     -- The new stuff starts here: Two new LEFT JOINs to track the rights you want
     left join person2right as p2r_1 using (person_id)
     left join person2right as p2r_4 using (person_id)
where
    -- Here is where you check if the rights exist
    (p2r_1.right_id = 1 and p2r_4.right_id = 4)
group by p.person_id;
```

Take a look to [this SQL fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a51b/12).

Comment: Is it possible to note some important advantage when comparing execution plan with the original OP's query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4c71/1 (really would like to know, since I'm not used to analyse MySQL execution plan).

Comment: [Check the `explain` result for both queries at SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a51b/12). My solution uses fewer rows per table to get the same result. Of course, performance should be tested with a bigger data set, and that should be OP's task.

Comment: In my experience I've found that using subqueries is (for all but the simplest and smallest problems) slower than using indexed columns directly. If a result can be obtained by filtering indexed columns (using `where`), then I prefer this filter than using a subquery. But that's only a matter of experience and preference

Comment: Yeah, I had already checked the explain but hadn't realized that difference you've shown. Thanks.

Comment: @Caffé as a first approach, if you see `using temporary`, that means that MySQL has to create a temp table at some point to execute the query; if you see `using filesort` that means that MySQL has to do another pass through all the data to return the result (and that is *sloooooow* if the result is big). As there's not such case here, the next things I see is: Are indexes being used? How many rows per table are being read? A little thumb-rule: multiply all the row numbers; the query with the smaller product is most times better

Comment: I understand your preference and strongly agree with you that performance should be tested. I always insist that performance questions should be accompanied by performance tests and not based only on assumptions.

Comment: Thank you again by all the execution plan explanation.

Comment: Your solution work well, but unfortunately it is not very well scalable. Every right which is added to the filter condition forces to use another join. But I'm aware of the fact that I did not ask for scalability. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking the rights in the where clause (avoiding the second left join)

```
...
WHERE 2 = (select count(*) 
           from person2right 
           where person_id = person.person_id
                 and right_id in (1, 4))
```

Comment: this just moves the subquery to the where condition, does not removes it